# How to fill the gaps and how to export the image

Tags: google-earth-engine

I would like to work with Landsat 7 images, but most of them have gaps. I would like to fill the gap., Secondly when I import the image in ArcMap, it is shown in black color.

Where am I getting wrong? I am sharing the code link here
https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fomerreshi90%2FAir-Quality-Parameters%3AKadalundi-2005

Also my code is:

```
var cloudMaskL457 = function(image) {
  var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
  // If the cloud bit (5) is set and the cloud confidence (7) is high
  // or the cloud shadow bit is set (3), then it's a bad pixel.
  var cloud = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 5)
                  .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 7))
                  .or(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 3));
  // Remove edge pixels that don't occur in all bands
  var mask2 = image. Mask().reduce(ee.Reducer.min());
  return image.updateMask(cloud.not()).update Mask(mask2);
};

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR')
                  .filterDate('2005-03-01', '2005-03-31')
                  .filterBounds(Aoi)
                  .map(cloudMaskL457);

var visParams = {
  bands: ['B3', 'B2', 'B1'],
  min: 0,
  max: 3000,
  gamma: 1.4,
};
Map.setCenter(-83.0539, 42.3159, 10);
//Map.addLayer(dataset, visParams);
var test=dataset.median()
Map.addLayer(test, visParams);

//.......exort ......

// Create a 3-band, 8-bit, color-IR composite to export.
var visualization =test.visualize({
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
  max: 0.4
});

// Create a task that you can launch from the Tasks tab.
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: visualization,
  description: 'Greenest_pixel_composite',
  scale: 30
});
```